# How to handle two values from a list simultaneously in a loop, attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, overriding, attributeerror

I need to iterate over a list of points to compute the distance of a line. But I'm getting an attribute error from this code I created. I think it's because I overload the addition function. How do I fix this so that I can compute the distances and store it in the list?

I tried to replace `dist = Line(i,i+1).distance` with `dist = Line(i[0],i[1]).distance` but it would yield an indexing error and I would need a overload function for indexing but it was not stated in the instructions.

```
import math

class Point:
    '''Class that creates points. Attributes: Eastings and Northings'''
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.eastings = x
        self.northings = y
    def getCoords(self):
        self.coords = (self.eastings,self.northings)
        return self.coords
    def setCoords(self,other_x,other_y):
        self.eastings = float(other_x)
        self.northings = float(other_y)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.eastings},{self.northings}"
    def __add__(self,new_point):
        return Line(self,new_point)

class Line(Point):
    '''Class that creates line object based on two points'''
    def __init__(self,start,end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.latitude = self.end.eastings - self.start.eastings
        self.departure = self.end.northings - self.start.northings
        self.distance = math.sqrt((self.latitude)**2 + (self.departure)**2)
        self.azimuth = math.degrees(math.atan2(self.departure,self.latitude))
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if index == 0:
            ans = self.start
        elif index == 1:
            ans = self.end
        else:
            print("invalid index")
        return ans

class Lot(Line):
    def __init__(self,name,lstpoints):
        self.name = name
        self.corners = self.__setCorners(lstpoints)
        self.lines = self.__getLines(lstpoints)
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def __setCorners(self,lstpoints):
        dct = {}
        for k,val in enumerate(lstpoints):
            new = {f"C{k+1}":val}
            dct.update(new)
        return dct
    def __getLines(self,lstpoints):
        lst_lines = []
        lst_dist = []
        for k,val in enumerate(lstpoints):
            if k == len(lstpoints)-1:
                break
            else:
                new = f"C{k+1}-C{k+2}"
                lst_lines.append(new)
        for i in lstpoints:
            dist = Line(i,i+1).distance
        dct_lines = dict(zip(lst_lines,lst_dis))
        return dct_lines

#test code that yields the error
a = Point(0,0)
b = Point(1,1)
c = Point(1,0.5)
lot = Lot("A1",[a,b,c])
type(Lot)
```

The error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-8644b897c98b> in <module>()
      2 b = Point(1,1)
      3 c = Point(1,0.5)
----> 4 lot = Lot("A1",[a,b,c])
      5 type(Lot)

<ipython-input-77-8492f1fa52db> in __init__(self, name, lstpoints)
      3         self.name = name
      4         self.corners = self.__setCorners(lstpoints)
----> 5         self.lines = self.__getLines(lstpoints)
      6         self.left = None
      7         self.right = None

<ipython-input-77-8492f1fa52db> in __getLines(self, lstpoints)
     22                 lst_lines.append(new)
     23         for i in lstpoints:
---> 24             dist = Line(i,i+1).distance
     25         dct_lines = dict(zip(lst_lines,lst_dis))
     26         return dct_lines

<ipython-input-65-7ac5af0efeef> in __add__(self, new_point)
     13         return f"{self.eastings},{self.northings}"
     14     def __add__(self,new_point):
---> 15         return Line(self,new_point)

<ipython-input-72-7743a2ec7710> in __init__(self, start, end)
      4         self.start = start
      5         self.end = end
----> 6         self.latitude = self.end.eastings - self.start.eastings
      7         self.departure = self.end.northings - self.start.northings
      8         self.distance = math.sqrt((self.latitude)**2 + (self.departure)**2)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'eastings'
```

Comment: You should review what inheritance means. Having `Line` class inherit `Point` class means the `Line` is a specific kind of `Point`. You could do the same without inheritance. This would make your code easier to understand and maintain for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to replace these lines:

```
for i in lstpoints:
        dist = Line(i,i+1).distance
```

by these:

```
for i in range(len(lstpoints)):
        dist = Line(lstpoints[i],lstpoints[i+1]).distance
```

Comment: it should be range(len(lstpoints)-1),unless got a list index out of range error

Comment: Thank you ! That worked. and thank you for the correction @leaf_yakitori

Comment: it doesn't correct, because a range in python doesn't include the last index of range